# Three slashes in sqlalchemy's engine url with sqlite?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

The [sqlalchemy docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/sqlite.html#connect-strings) says:

> The sqlite `:memory:` identifier is the default if no filepath is present. Specify `sqlite://` and nothing else:
>
> ```
> # in-memory database
> e = create_engine('sqlite://')
> ```

Can I, however, use three slashes instead of just two (`sqlite:///`)? Or can I use `:memory:` itself (`sqlite:///:memory:`)? This is so that I could define all the engine properties in a config file and do something like this:

```
url = f'{dialect}+{driver}://{username}:{password}@{host}:{port}/{path}'
```

Instead of:

```
url = f'{dialect}+{driver}://{username}:{password}@{host}:{port}{'/' + path if path else ''}'
```

But I could just do

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: @StephenRauch Yeah, I got no idea how to confirm whether it works or not... I didn't get any error but that's not a confirmation of it working. Tried out printing all of the engine's properties like `url` and `dialect` etc. but they all seem to just refer to the original string.

Comment: "The file specification for the SQLite database is taken as the “database” portion of the URL.", which is chars to the right of the 3rd slash. If no database portion is present, it defaults to ":memory:", so 3 slashes seem fine. `sqlite:///:memory:` should also give you a mem db, as the database portion is passed as is.

Comment: @IljaEverilä Alright thanks, I think that works, at least it produces no errors... I found a better solution though! http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/engines.html#sqlalchemy.engine.url.URL

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While this isn't a direct answer to the question I asked (XY problem?), I found a "correct" way to handle creating URL string from configs. It seems that SQLAlchemy already has a built-in function dedicated to this, meet [`sqlalchemy.engine.url.URL`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/engines.html#sqlalchemy.engine.url.URL):

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.engine.url import URL

configs = {
    'drivername': 'sqlite',
    'username': '',
    'password': '',
    'host': '',
    'port': '',
    'database': ':memory:',
    'query': '',
}

engine = create_engine(URL(**configs))
```